# Can users create folders and files inside of shared folders with edit permissions in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

If I share a folder in Google Drive with someone and give them edit permissions can they create files and folders within that folder?

Comment: What does "edit permissions" mean to you?

Comment: Try it with non-critical files.

Comment: By "edit permissions" meaning I open the sharing settings for the folder and selecting that that person has permission to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can add files and folders. I use the Google Drive App (no access to cloud sites at work), and I just added a second email account I have. When adding, there is an icon to edit the level of access the person has. It defaults to "Can organize, add, and edit".

I manage a couple projects with Drive and can verify that people I share the folders with can add files. Hope this helps!
- JR

[image]